# Special Characters in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, special-characters

So I'm trying to access a JSON callback that looks like

```
{ 
  "response": {

      "data":  {

          "@data": {
             "property": "value"
             "property": "value"

          }

      }           
}
```

and keep getting errors in vscode when trying to access the @data object.

I've tried

```
response.data[@data]
```

as well adjusting special characters in the config file and a replace function for @

Comment: are you missing a single quote in response.data['@data'] ? is that the problem ?

Comment: It's `object.response.data['@data']`, but apart from that it should work just fine.

Comment: wow. love when it's this easy. hate when i'm this dumb. thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to put quotes around @data

like this:

```
response.data['@data']
```